# Spring 3.1 Environment Abstraction and EJB integration

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, ejb, environment, abstraction

I'm trying to use the new environment abstraction in our Java EE/EJB application. We're already using `SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor` to inject Spring Beans into EJBs by using the standard beanRefContext.xml to bootstrap the shared application context for the Java EE app.

Now I've written a concrete Environment class (derived from Spring 3.1 AbstractEnvironment) which uses some kind of environment "auto" detection to select the correct active profile for the machine on which the app is running on. With this feature our app can be delivered with all properties for all environements (inside the ear) and auto select the correct property set.

The problem is now that org.springframework.beans.factory.access.SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.createDefinition(String, String) builds a bean factory group around the beans/context in beanRefContext.xml using the StandardEnvironment class, and I see no simple way to configure the environment implementation to use here without rewriting(overwriting) some part of SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.

Is there a simple solution for this, or is s.th. planned in the direction for supporting to specify the Environment implementation with the EJB/Java EE integration?